# Finding the direction user facing in ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I wish to know what direction my camera is facing in ARKit, so that the operation I worked on the objects in front of me is correct (says swipe left to move left).

Right now I have tried using POV direction (does not work as it is always positive) and node direction (photo.worldFront.z - this will work unless rotation is applied, once rotated more than 180 degrees the direction is wrong).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You were right looking at `pointOfView` first.

Hovewer while `rotation` and `eulerAngles` both describe what direction the camera is facing, it's not straightforward to use them when *working with objects* such as placing or moving objects in *front of you* which is the space of the camera.

Instead, set up your position or movement vector in world space, then transform it to the camera's space using the camera's `transform`.

In Obj-C it would go like this:

```
simd_float4x4 transform = self.sceneView.pointOfView.simdTransform;
simd_float4 myPosInWorldSpace = simd_make_float4(0.0, 0.0, -0.5, 1);
simd_float4 myPosInCamSpace = simd_mul(transform, myPosInWorldSpace);
```

Set the position of an object to `myPosInCamSpace`. The example above puts the object at `z=-0.5` in camera space, which is half meter ahead of the camera in AR.

To *move* an object that is already in front of the camera to 5 centimeters to the right, goes like this:

```
simd_float4x4 transform = self.sceneView.pointOfView.simdTransform;
transform.columns[3].xyz=0; //drop cam translation
simd_float4 myVecInWorldSpace = simd_make_float4(0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
simd_float4 myVecInCamSpace = simd_mul(transform, myVecInWorldSpace);
```

Add `myVecInCamSpace` to the position of the object in front of you.

### First Amendment

If you just need camera yaw in full 360° (−π, π] for logging or whatever:

```
simd_float4x4 transform = self.sceneView.pointOfView.simdTransform;
simd_float3 cam_right = transform.columns[0].xyz; //for completeness
simd_float3 cam_up = transform.columns[1].xyz;  //for completeness
simd_float3 cam_ahead = transform.columns[2].xyz;
float yaw = atan2f(cam_ahead.x, cam_ahead.z);
```

Comment: Please, can you add Swift version of your answer?

Comment: @kelin Sorry, I have zero experience with Swift.